# Getting Reference (url link) from another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to link a cell to an external file. The name of the external file changes daily though.

I created a cell that contains the full address of the external file (**C:\Users\Main\Desktop\data\History\02092013.csv**)

I then named that cell **HistoryFileReference**

So then why does this not work?

```
='HistoryFileReference'!$A$2
```

When I press enter, a window named "Update Values: HistoryFileReference" pops up, asking me to choose a file.

edit: I don't want to "update links" via excel. Thanks

Comment: You can only link to an external Excel file - there is no "A2" in a CSV file.

Comment: Actually, I am already linking to other csv files (comma separated) and everything works great.

Comment: Will your csv file be open? If yes then it is possible using `INDIRECT` else you will have to use VBA

Comment: All that did was create a hyperlink to my file. I want to retrieve the contents of the cell. I don't understand, opening the CSV file, I see a standard excel table. Why does `='C:\Users\Main\Desktop\data\History\02092013.csv'!$A$2` work, but the latter does not?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Does the file have to be open at all times? Or is it enough if I open the file and close it?

Comment: For the formula to work, you will have to open the file and once the formula updates, close the file.

Comment: Excellent, I don't have any issues with that (I will write a script). Thanks

Comment: @pufAmuf - but you first have to open that file in Excel, right? At which point it's an Excel file, not CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you will have to manually put brackets in the file name and then store it as

`C:\Users\Main\Desktop\data\History\[02092013.csv]` in the cell which you have named as `HistoryFileReference`

Now open the CSV file and leave it open. Go back to the above sheet and type this formula

`=INDIRECT("'" & HistoryFileReference & "02092013'!$A$2")`

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you are done :)

**Caution**: Next time you open the file, do not click on `Update Links` else all the values generated by the above formula will change into `#REF!` as `Indirect` doesn't work with close files.

For the sake of an example, I have place a csv file in `C:\` as shown in the screenshot below and I am trying to retrieve values from Cell `A1`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. Why do I need to use `& "02092013'` however? I wanted to use the formula because I never know what the file name will be. I wrote a script to insert the full path of the file into a csv file (history.csv). That data is then loaded into my main sheet, and the cell is named **HistoryFileReference**. The rest you know. The only reference I do know which stays the same is **HistoryFileReference**, but I never know if the file name is *02092013* or *20092013*.

Comment: The csv sheet, when you open in excel will have the same name as the file unless you manually change it or the name of the file is too long for a sheet name. When you manually type a formula, you will notice that the sheet name is also specified. And hence the use of "02092013" in the formula.

Comment: This is the formula that you would type manually or will get when you link to the cell manually `='C:\[02092013.csv]02092013'!$A$1` (As per my example)

Comment: Mhm okay, so in the case of `=INDIRECT("'" & HistoryFileReference & "02092013'!$A$2")`, can I also retrieve the `02092013` part from another named cell? I could then write a script to write the full path and the full name separately into different cells.

Comment: Great! I'm having issues and getting errors with this `=INDIRECT("'" & HistoryFileReference & HistoryFileName"'"!$A$2")` I think the issue is probably with the quote marks, but not sure how to order them.

Comment: `=INDIRECT("'" & HistoryFileReference & HistoryFileName & "'!$A$2")` I am assuming that `HistoryFileName` has `02092013`